# Spring Boot 3 connecting to ElasticSearch 7.16

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am running an Elasticsearch with Version 7.16 and connect to it with an Spring Boot 2 Service using the Spring Elasticsearch client library in version 4.

On Updating to Spring Boot 3 the new Elasticsearch client library 5 is being used.

My question is: Is it possible to connect to Elasticsearch 7.16 instance with the new Elasticsearch client library in version 5?

I tried connecting with the new client, but always getting this error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: http://localhost:9200: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:933) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1519) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:852) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1367) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1301) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalAddressResolver.resolveRemoteAddress(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:666) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalAddressResolver.resolveRemoteAddress(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:637) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.processPendingRequest(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:472) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.lease(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:280) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:295) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.requestConnection(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:381) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.start(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:130) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:116) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:138) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:296) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.5.3.jar:8.5.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:288) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.5.3.jar:8.5.3]
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:147) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.3.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1518) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchTemplate.lambda$search$14(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:323) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:538) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchTemplate.search(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:323) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
```

When using the deprecated client implementation, i am getting this error during compile:

```
ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.erhlc.AbstractReactiveElasticsearchConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@21588809]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:374) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:748) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:680) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1632) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:532) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1278) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:865) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:853) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:840) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at com.bbraun.nemo.NemoApplication.main(NemoApplication.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/support/IndicesOptions
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.action.support.IndicesOptions
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you configure the configuration when using Spring Data Elasticsearch5? Having "http://" in the hostname seems wrong to me.

Check the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/5.0.6/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-4.4-5.0.new-clients). You can still configure to use the old client, but keep in mind that this option will be removed with Spring Data Elasticsearch 5.2 (November 2023)

Comment: Thank's a lot! Not having http:// in host fixed it for me using the new client!